# Why is 'username' declared twice in the stock UserCreationForm?

Tags: django, django-forms

In the stock `UserCreationForm`, `username` is already declared as a `RegexField`, but how come it's also declared in the `Meta` class?

Here's the snippet:

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    A form that creates a user, with no privileges, from the given username and
    password.
    """
    error_messages = {
        'duplicate_username': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        'password_mismatch': _("The two password fields didn't match."),
    }
    username = forms.RegexField(label=_("Username"), max_length=30,
        regex=r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
        help_text=_("Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and "
                    "@/./+/-/_ only."),
        error_messages={
            'invalid': _("This value may contain only letters, numbers and "
                         "@/./+/-/_ characters.")})
    password1 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password confirmation"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        help_text=_("Enter the same password as above, for verification."))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username",)

    def clean_username(self):
        # Since User.username is unique, this check is redundant,
        # but it sets a nicer error message than the ORM. See #13147.
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        try:
            User._default_manager.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['duplicate_username'],
            code='duplicate_username',
        )

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
                code='password_mismatch',
            )
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields in meta is not a declaration, it is saying what fields from the model to use in the form.